# In BACnet VTS scripting is there a way to implement functions/macros?

Tags: bacnet

In my VTS scripts almost all the SEND, EXPECT commands have similar parameters(Like DEST ADDRESS, DEST NETWORK etc). So is there a way to avoid duplication using a function or macro. I had not seen any functions/macros in the example scripts of VTS.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the VTS script is limited in its possibilities. Something like function macros do not exist. But you can use rather than hard-coded values​​, parameters such as IUT_ADDR for an address.

Alternatively, you generate the VTS scripts through an additional tool. A Python script is conceivable that functions as a kind of preprocessor and create the VTS script in prebuild step.